# Can upgrade RAM for MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) ..?

Tags: memory, macbook, upgrade

My mac is MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) 8gb RAM. Too slow when running Xcode or android studio. I want to upgrade *gb to 16gb RAM, is it possible ? That because i read RAM for this mac are solder.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. The last upgradable models were 2012.

Comment: And in any case adding RAM does not speed up the system unless you were already using more than the physical RAM which means swap (or equivalent) may have been used thus slowing down the system. Otherwise you're barking at the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not be able to add additional RAM at this point.

Your only option for 16GB of memory was to have opted for it at the time of purchase as the 8GB and 16GB configurations available for your model are both onboard memory.

From [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp715) for the specs for your laptop:

```
Memory
8GB of 1866MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory
Configurable to 16GB.
```

.....which is later clarified on the same page as:

```
Configure to Order  
Configure your MacBook Pro with these options, only at apple.com:

16GB of 1866MHz LPDDR3  onboard memory
```